# Selectize.js render selectize-control before select

Tags: selectize.js

How I would render a selectize instance with selectize-control wrap before the select element?

Originally it rends like this

```
<select>...</select>
<div class="selectize-control multi">...</div>
```

How I would do this

```
<div class="selectize-control multi">...</div>
<select>...</select>
```

The plugin url is http://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/

Answer (score 0):

Inside selectize.js, search for this line

```
$input.attr('tabindex', -1).hide().after(self.$wrapper);
```

replace it with

```
$input.attr('tabindex', -1).hide().before(self.$wrapper);
```

But I think you should search for a better solution.